# How to set QField project with specific scales but not limiting the reach?

Tags: qgis-2.18, qfield

Oke so far I know how to create QField project with QField sync, I find it very easy, but I have to say it is quite unstable since it will close the app down after I try to zoom on the map on a specific scale. I suppose this is because my base map (which consist of a Ortho Photo of the entire area of the "community") is just to big for calculations.

To put points on a map this is actually not a problem since I just need to locate by GPS by standing next to object, and then putting the point in.

However I also want to use QFIELD to create "polygon" shapefiles on the field. And if zooming on a base map layer like this causes a crash, it will give problems.

We use the ortho photo in QGIS desktop to draw, on a scale around 1:150-1:250. The reason since the picture is most clearer then, because we want to make sure the error margin is a less as possible when drawing by hand. At that scale range the picture is as much clear as we can get it and NOT to much pixelated.

In QGIS desktop we just zoom out to a bigger scale and then just relocate, so our project view is NOT LIMITED to this scale range.

So how do I make sure that the QGIS field projects is only limited to a scale of 1:150-1:250 in terms of zoom, but not sacrificing the reach of the base map layer? This is because we can assume that we just can relocate by using the GPS.